# Play sound when app is closed without hardcoded path to sound

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to play my own custom notification sound to set my app apart from a system default sound. So, when I receive a GCM message, I have a function called `generateNotification` that puts a notification in the status bar and plays a sound.

Currently, I set the path to the sound like this:

```
String GENERAL_NOTIFICATION_SOUND = "android.resource://" + MyActivity.getInstance().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound_file;
```

This works when the app is open, even when the app is recently closed. But if the app is closed by Android's memory management, then `MyActivity.getInstance()` returns `null`, and my app crashes with a NullPointerException without properly displaying a notification because it couldn't resolve the path.

I believe I could just fix this by hardcoding the path, but I feel like there has to be a better way. How can you set a path to files that need to be accessed when the app might not be open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not have a `MyActivity.getInstance()`, as that is a memory leak.

Second, whatever code is raising the `Notification` already has access to a `Context`, as that is where you get a `NotificationManager` from. `getPackageName()` is a method on `Context`. So, for example, your GCM `IntentService` is a `Context`, and so not only can it use `getSystemService()` to retrieve a `NotificationManager`, but it can call `getPackageName()` on itself to find out your app's package name.

Comment: This is excellent - thanks for pointing out the obvious. Silly me. Would you mind elaborating on why "MyActivity.getInstance()" is a memory leak and bad?

Comment: @unexpected62: It is a memory leak because an `Activity` should get garbage collected after it is destroyed (e.g., user presses BACK), but a static reference to it will prevent that. This means that the activity, and everything it holds onto (widgets, model data, etc.) all cannot get garbage collected, which represents a memory leak.

Comment: Oh I see. In my implementation this is actually desired. I'm using AndEngine and I only have one Activity and I switch screens by switching "scenes" which is a component of the engine - so this is desired behavior for me. Thanks for the concern and explanation though.